# python Google Analytics setUserId

Tags: python, google-analytics, userid

When triggering server events to Google Analytics, I can set the user ID in various programming languages as described in the official docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/user-id?platform=apps#swift

However, it is not mentioned, nor can I find anywhere, how to do the same when you work with Python.

Anyone knows?

Comment: Try looking for firebase analytics see if you can go though that.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your approach, that basically demonstrates how you've used the library and where you want to add the client ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google only shows how to set the user id for their SDKs/frameworks. Python is not something they have a supported framework for in this case. You should refer to the manual of the library you're using for it.

If you're not using a library for sending events, but rather building the requests from scratch, you want to refer to the [measurement protocol documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4).

Answer (score -1):

You don't do it in python but in Javascript,
if you go to the same link you mentioned and click Website option you get the code of sending the id

```
gtag('config', 'MEASUREMENT_ID', {
'user_id': 'USER_ID' 
});
```

Comment: Server events. Measurement Protocol.